# How to set a variable in an alias for a number of directories?

Tags: bashrc, alias

I'm working in a large computing cluster and when I submit a job, the system assign an ID for the job and creates a file with that ID for the calculation. The directory path is too long, so I want to make an alias with a variable so that I can include the job ID and reach the directory without typing the whole path. (After the job is done, that file is copied to my main directory, but when I want to check it during mid-calculation I have to use a long path.) My first attempt was something like this:

```
alias job-$a="cd ~/many/many/folders/later/job.$a"
```

In similar topics people have suggested using 'functions' instead of 'alias', but I couldn't manage to fit those solutions into my case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So a function `jobcd() { cd ~/many/many/folders/later/job."$1"; }` invoked as `jobcd <id>` doesn't work for your case?

Comment: @steeldriver It does now, I must have made a typo while defining it. Sorry for the stupid question.